# Where is this formula about cyclotomic polynomials proved?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

In an article "Generalized Reciprocals, Factors of Dickson
Polynomials and Generalized Cyclotomic
Polynomials over Finite Field" by Fitzgerald and Yucas I see
on page 18 in the proof of Lemma 7.2 (2) mentioned a factorization
formula by cyclotomic polynomials as
$$x^n+1=\prod_{d|n,\frac nd \text{odd}}\Phi_{2d}(x)$$
This is new to me and probably I never saw it in the literature 
available to me.

Does anybody know where this formula is proved ?

Comment: How should the index of the product be interpreted, e.g. when $n=3$?

Comment: This reads for $n=3$ as $$\Phi_{2\cdot 1}(x)\Phi_{2\cdot 3}(x)$$ with the $2$ divisors $1$ and $3$ of $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are familiar with the formula $\displaystyle x^n - 1 = \prod_{d | n}\Phi_d$.

Noticing that $(x^n-1)(x^n+1) = x^{2n}-1$, you have $\displaystyle x^n+1 = \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^n-1} =  \frac{\prod_{d | 2n}\Phi_d}{\prod_{d | n}\Phi_d} = \prod_{d | 2n, d  \nmid n}\Phi_d$.

Now $\{d, d | 2n \text{ and } d \nmid n \} = \{ 2d, d | n \text{ and } 2d \nmid n \} = \{2d, d | n \text{ and } \frac{n}{d} \text{ odd} \}$, which gives the wanted identity.